# MeteorJS how to capture client side image requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, meteor

I have an app that involves a lot of images hosted on other websites. In my collections that have images, the url of the image is saved in a field that is sent to the client. This is then placed within the src attribute of an img tag using handlebars. This works in that the image makes its way to the client, however it is slow to have the client download all the images. Is there a way in meteor to capture this request the client makes and check a storage for the image that can be piped to the client. Currently I am trying to use WebApp like so:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice(0, 0,  {
route: '/',
handle: function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    if (req.url.slice(0, 13) === '/images/?url=') {
        console.log(req.url); //function never gets here
```

...
However, as the comment says, this only fires the request of the user first coming to the server and opens a web socket. Thus, I can not capture any image requests. How would I be able to do this in meteor?
 Any other tips on how to optimize for a meteor app with remote images would also help.